# setLayouParams didn't work in cardView

Tags: android, cardview

I have two activities each of them bounded to the same adapter one of them when I click on item it opens the second activity with all data, the cardview width is wrap_content it works fine in first activity but in second I want the width to be `match_parent` where I make the layout horizontal I try `setLayoutParams()`
but did not work

```
public AzkaarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    CardView cardView=(CardView)parent.findViewById(R.id.cardview);

    CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams)cardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = CardView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    ...
```

And I have this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.nourabosily.aa.azkaar.AzkaarAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AzkaarAdapter.java:37)
at com.nourabosily.aa.azkaar.AzkaarAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AzkaarAdapter.java:23)
```

this is the code of adapter

```
public class AzkaarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AzkaarAdapter.AzkaarViewHolder>  {
    ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms=new ArrayList<AzkarForm>();
    Context ctx;

public  AzkaarAdapter (ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms,Context ctx){
    this.azkarForms=azkarForms;
    this.ctx=ctx;
}
@Override
public AzkaarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {        CardView cardView=(CardView)parent.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams)cardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = CardView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout,parent,false);
    AzkaarViewHolder azkaarViewHolder=new AzkaarViewHolder(view,ctx,azkarForms);
    ViewGroup viewGroup=(ViewGroup)parent.getParent();
    CardView.LayoutParams params=(CardView.LayoutParams)(viewGroup.getLayoutParams());
    params.height=800;
    return azkaarViewHolder;

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AzkaarViewHolder holder, int position) {


    AzkarForm azkarForm=azkarForms.get(position);
    if(ctx instanceof MainActivity) {
        holder.sample.setText(azkarForm.getSample());
        holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(azkarForm.getNumber()));
    }else{
        holder.sample.setText(azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
        holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(azkarForm.getNumber()));
    }
    int width =holder.itemView.getWidth();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height= RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return azkarForms.size();
}

public static class AzkaarViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView sample, number;
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms = new ArrayList<AzkarForm>();

    public AzkaarViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx, ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms) {
        super(itemView);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        if(this.ctx instanceof MainActivity)
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.azkarForms = azkarForms;
        sample = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sample);
        number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        AzkarForm azkarForm=azkarForms.get(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this.ctx,DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("numbers",azkarForm.getNumber());
        intent.putExtra("sample",azkarForm.getSample());
        intent.putExtra("complete",azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
        intent.putExtra("position",position);
        this.ctx.startActivity(intent);

    }
}

}
```

and this is the code of layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardview">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sample"
            android:text="Noura Ali Bosily"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: can you post your full code on that page?

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            @Override
        public AzkaarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {        
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout,parent,false);
            AzkaarViewHolder azkaarViewHolder=new AzkaarViewHolder(view,ctx,azkarForms);

            return azkaarViewHolder;

        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AzkaarViewHolder holder, int position) {


            CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams)holder.cardView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = CardView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        holder.cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            AzkarForm azkarForm=azkarForms.get(position);
     ViewGroup viewGroup=(ViewGroup)holder.cardview.getParent();
            CardView.LayoutParams params=(CardView.LayoutParams)(viewGroup.getLayoutParams());
            params.height=800;

            if(ctx instanceof MainActivity) {
                holder.sample.setText(azkarForm.getSample());
                holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(azkarForm.getNumber()));
            }else{
                holder.sample.setText(azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
                holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(azkarForm.getNumber()));
            }
            int width =holder.itemView.getWidth();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height= RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

        }

public static class AzkaarViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView sample, number;
    Context ctx;
    CardView cardView
    ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms = new ArrayList<AzkarForm>();

    public AzkaarViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx, ArrayList<AzkarForm> azkarForms) {
        super(itemView);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        if(this.ctx instanceof MainActivity)
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.azkarForms = azkarForms;
        sample = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sample);
        number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        cardView=(CardView)parent.findViewById(R.id.cardview);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        AzkarForm azkarForm=azkarForms.get(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this.ctx,DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("numbers",azkarForm.getNumber());
        intent.putExtra("sample",azkarForm.getSample());
        intent.putExtra("complete",azkarForm.getComplete_morning());
        intent.putExtra("position",position);
        this.ctx.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: It's great that you solved the problem. Can you add an explanation of why it works so the OP knows what to do in the future?

Comment: The answer is simple. You get NPE(NullPointerException) when there is no value for a view or a variable. In this case,View value is null so, the view needs to get it's value before it is used. in onCreateViewHolder() you don't get value to your view. you can do this in onBindViewHolder(). That's it.

Comment: I used it but I have this error                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
although I haven't FrameLayout

Comment: why do you want to use view group here?

Comment: Thanks it works fine I put this code RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview).setLayoutParams(params); in bindViewHolder() method

Answer (score 0):

```
CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams)cardView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = CardView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Instead try using,

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
holder.cardView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

do it in

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AzkaarViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

cardView should be in ViewHolder.

Comment: I used it but the same

Comment: cardView should be in ViewHolder.CardView is your parent in layout.Then exactly whats your requirement. What you are trying to change.Why don't you use layout_height = "match_parent" in xml file.

Comment: thanks alot I make change from two answers I put the code in bindViewholder and change the layout of cardview to RelativeLayout RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview).setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: I want to change the layout_height at run time for specific case I used the card view in two activities one of them I need the height to fill activity